# PHP Tool Integration (PTI) with Eclipse Mars not working

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

Not working at all. Is it broken?

```
An internal error occurred during: "PHP CodeSniffer".
org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.preferences.PHPDebuggersRegistry.getDebuggerConfiguration(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/debugger/AbstractDebuggerConfiguration;

An internal error occurred during: "PHPUnit".
org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.preferences.PHPDebuggersRegistry.getDebuggerConfiguration(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/debugger/AbstractDebuggerConfiguration;

An internal error occurred during: "PHP Copy/Paste Detector".
org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.preferences.PHPDebuggersRegistry.getDebuggerConfiguration(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/debugger/AbstractDebuggerConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the nighlty update site fixes the issue:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/

Comment: Unfortunately this solution no longer works - the latest nightly of August 25 reports * Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.6.0.201508252253 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.6.0.201508252253) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.core.feature.group 5.3.0' but it could not be found*

Answer (score 2):

PTI use PDT internal api, which was changed. We reverted to old api and PTI will be again compatible since next version (3.6,  scheduled for 2015-09-25)

See also bugzilla bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473050